# Find out the size of open terminal

Tags: terminal

Within a desktop environment we can resize terminals ([GNOME Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal) for example) for our convenience.

How can I know the size of the terminal in terms of pixels or number of columns and rows?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you issue the command

```
stty size
```

it returns the size of the current terminal in rows and columns. Example:

```
$ stty size
24 80
```

You can read the rows and columns into variables like this (thanks to [Janis' comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102438/janis)):

```
$ read myrows mycols < <(stty size)
```

Obtaining the size in pixels requires knowledge of your screen's resolution and I don't think `stty` has direct access to such information.

Comment: sir is it not possible to get output in terms of pixels ?

Comment: Note that in `bash` the `echo` command in this answer will not see the variables, since the `read` in the pipeline will be executed in a subshell. (It works in `ksh`, though.) For `bash` you may want to use, e.g., `read myrows mycols < <( stty size )`.

Comment: Every Linux distro I've used has `resize` which outputs a shell script to set the size in environment variables.

Comment: No, you can't get the pixel dimensions of a tty because its a character device and doesn't have pixels.

Answer (score 6):

```
tput cols; tput lines
```

This will display columns and rows.

Answer (score 3):

In a *desktop environment*, you are using X, and the `xwininfo` utility can show the size of the window in pixels.  Also, if you are running on the desktop (and not, for instance, remotely connected), the terminal emulator provides a variable `$WINDOWID` which you can use as a parameter to `xwininfo`, e.g.,

```
xwininfo -id $WINDOWID
```

and get a listing list this:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0xc00025 "uxterm"

  Absolute upper-left X:  65
  Absolute upper-left Y:  167
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  22
  Width: 624
  Height: 577
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x22
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 1
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x21 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +65+167  -589+167  -589-256  +65-256
  -geometry 103x42+65+145
```

In this example, the lines with `Width` and `Height` are the size in *pixels*.  The last line, with `-geometry` gives the size in *characters* (as well as the position of the upper-left corner — in pixels).

Talking of *resizing* the window, the `resize` program shows the number of lines and columns.  For this example, it shows

```
$ resize
set noglob;
setenv COLUMNS '103';
setenv LINES '42';
unset noglob;
```

The question did not indicate how the information might be used, but since the output is text, in a predictable format, it is readily scripted.  Here is a simple example using awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$WINDOWID" ]
then
    xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | awk '
    BEGIN { px = 0; py = 0; chars = "?x?"; }
    /Height:/ { py = $2; }
    /Width:/ { px = $2; }
    /-geometry/ { chars = $2; sub("+.*","",chars); }
    END { printf "%dx%d pixels, %s chars\n", py, px, chars; }'
else
    printf '? no WINDOWID found\n'
fi
```

which prints

```
577x624 pixels, 103x42 chars
```

Comment: In `GNOME Shell 3.36.7` session doesn't brings `WINDOWID` variable set :(

Comment: The terminal sets WINDOWID (not the window manager).  There's a [known defect](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/17) in gnome-terminal.